# Change JSON string structure

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON string which looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "queryResult": {
            "A": "12-04-2014",
            "B": 1
        }
    },
    {
        "queryResult": {
            "A": "13-04-2014",
            "B": 2
        }
    },
    {
        "queryResult": {
            "A": "14-04-2014",
            "B": 3
        }
    }
]
```

And I need to parse it and change it to this

```
[
    {
        "A": "12-04-2014",
        "B": 1
    },
    {
        "A": "13-04-2014",
        "B": 2
    },
    {
        "A": "14-04-2014",
        "B": 3
    }
]
```

I already have a function for making that change, which is:

```
function justAnExample() {
    var jsonData = exampleJSON(); //Obtains the JSON
    var finalJSON=JSON.stringify(jsonData[0]['queryResult']);
    for (var i = 1; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
        finalJSON = finalJSON+','+JSON.stringify(jsonData[i]['queryResult']);
    }
    return JSON.parse('[' + finalJSON + ']');
}
```

But, this method uses stringifying and then parsing JSON to recreate the JSON object, which works, but is there a better solution, in which I can work with the object notation itself.

P.S: I know the term "JSON object" is a semi-pseudo thing, and that only the JSON notation/format matters, but, just need to confirm if this is the proper way to do it.

**Edit**

Please find a JS fiddle for the problem

http://jsfiddle.net/mukilr/uJV54/

Comment: Does your "JSON string" look exactly like you have shown?

Comment: Yes, this is the exact representation.

Comment: Can you please create a jsfiddle with that exact string?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mukilr/uJV54/

Comment: @thefourtheye The fiddle is done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
var json = [
    {
        "queryResult": {
            "A": "12-04-2014",
            "B": 1
        }
    },
    {
        "queryResult": {
            "A": "13-04-2014",
            "B": 2
        }
    },
    {
        "queryResult": {
            "A": "14-04-2014",
            "B": 3
        }
    }
];

var out = [];


for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++){
out[i] = json[i].queryResult;
}
```

check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p95bA/)

**EDIT**
This is your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sfarsaci/uJV54/1/) updated